# documentation of splunk "ifnull" function?

Tags: splunk

We're using the `ifnull` function in one of our Splunk queries (yes, `ifnull` not `isnull`), and I wanted to look up the logic just to be sure, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

It is [referenced in a few spots](http://docs.splunk.com/Special:SplunkSearch/docs?q=ifnull):

- [SPL data types and clauses](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.5.1612/SearchReference/ListOfDataTypes)
- [Eval](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.5.1612/SearchReference/Eval)
- [Where](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.5.1612/SearchReference/Where)

But I can't find a definition/explanation anywhere on what it actually does. Google seems to be of no help either (constantly wants to redirect me to `isnull`).

In particular it's also not listed in "[common evaluation functions](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/6.5.1612/SearchReference/CommonEvalFunctions)".

Can anyone point me to some documentation about `ifnull`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR; it's an alias for `coalesce`

Wow, it really is hidden! I managed to find it on my local instance here: `./etc/system/default/searchbnf.conf`

> example4 = coalesce(null(), "Returned value", null())
>   comment4 = Takes any number of arguments and returns the first value that is not null. The **ifnull** function does the exact same thing, so both names are acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for digging into it!